# MSAL node - in memory cache always empty when using ConfidentialClientApplication.acquireTokenByClientCredential

Tags: node.js, azure-ad-msal, msal

I am using msal node the latest version.
This is my code:

```
 protected getConfidentialClientApplication(tenantId: string): ConfidentialClientApplication {
        if (this.confidentialClientApplication) {
            return this.confidentialClientApplication;
        }

        this.confidentialClientApplication = new ConfidentialClientApplication({
            auth: {
                clientId: this.tokenConfiguration.clientId,
                clientCertificate: {
                    thumbprint: this.tokenConfiguration.thumbprint,
                    privateKey: this.tokenConfiguration.privateKey,
                    x5c: this.tokenConfiguration.publicKey
                },
                authority: this.tokenConfiguration.authority + tenantId,
                knownAuthorities: [this.tokenConfiguration.authority + tenantId]
            },
        });

        return this.confidentialClientApplication;
    }

protected getTokenRequest(correlationId: string): ClientCredentialRequest {
    return {
        scopes: this.getScopes(),
        correlationId: correlationId,
        azureRegion: "TryAutoDetect"
    };
}
```

and I am calling this method:

```
this.getConfidentialClientApplication(tenantId).acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest)
```

If I am watching the response of the request, the token exist but the account is empty.
Also,   `msalTokenCache.getAllAccounts()`;
is always an empty list. How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Document-[msal-authentication-flows using client-credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials)

> For client credentials flow, where you are obtaining tokens without user interaction, it's important to understand that there are  typically no user accounts involved.

> The client credentials flow is intended for server-to-server
> communication and doesn't deal with user accounts or user
> interactions.

> When you use the client credentials flow to obtain a token, there won't be any cached accounts to retrieve using `msalTokenCache.getAllAccounts()`.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
const { ConfidentialClientApplication , PublicClientApplication} =  require("@azure/msal-node");            
const  tenantId  =  "********-****-****-****-***********";   
const  tokenConfiguration  = {
clientId:  "********-****-****-****-***********", 
clientSecret:  "**********************************", // Add your client secret here   
authority:  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",  
};    
const  confidentialClientApplication  =  new  ConfidentialClientApplication({    
auth: {   
clientId:  tokenConfiguration.clientId,  
clientSecret:  tokenConfiguration.clientSecret,   
authority:  tokenConfiguration.authority  +  tenantId,    
knownAuthorities: [tokenConfiguration.authority  +  tenantId]   
}    
});
  
const  tokenRequest  = {    
scopes: [`${tokenConfiguration.clientId}/.default`], // Replace with the scope you need  
azureRegion:  "TryAutoDetect" 
}; 
(async () => {  
try { 
const  response  =  await  confidentialClientApplication.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);
console.log("Token response:", response);
const  cachedAccounts  =  await  confidentialClientApplication.getTokenCache().getAllAccounts();

console.log("Cached accounts:", cachedAccounts);

} catch (error) {

console.error("Token acquisition error:", error);

}

})();
```

**Response:**

[image]